# Can you extract data points from cluster levels in ggplot::geom_density_2d_filled?

Tags: r, ggplot2, cluster-computing

For my data, each patient has numeric data from 2 samples, which I've plotted as individual coordinates for each patient and used `ggplot::geom_density_2d_filled` to visualize clusters.

Ultimately, I have many more sample pairs for the same patients which I'm visualizing the same way, and I want to see if certain patients are always clustered near each other. However, I can't find a way to extract the specific points (with their associated patient ID) that fall within each specific level/ cluster of the plot. Is there any way to do this? Should I be using a different approach not involving `ggplot::geom_density_2d_filled`?

Edit:
Here's a preview of my data and the code I used to generate the graphs

```
   patient_ID pLPE_18.0 Cl_total_18.0
1      993397 1796.4549     0.9379375
2      993398 1991.2818     0.5847325
3      993477 2638.1399     1.3453963
4      993480 3366.4634     2.2080976
5      993481 1778.2783     1.3255837
6      993490 2409.2275     1.2605374
```

```
st1 <- ggplot(PC_16_mod, aes(x=Cl_total_18.0, y=pLPE_18.0, label=patient_ID)) +
  geom_point(size=0.5, shape=16)
st1 + geom_density_2d_filled(alpha = 0.5)
```

The actual data set I have has each column as a different sample type, but I'm just showing 2 since I'm analyzing them 2 at a time, if that makes sense

Comment: Could you please share some code you tried and data using `dput`? So we can help you better.

Comment: Although it is possible, this doesn't seem like the optimal way to find out if patients are clustered together. What exactly is it that you are trying to find out? Is it whether significant clusters exist, or whether you can classify patients as belonging to a particular cluster?

Comment: I'm really just trying to see if there are any patterns between the patients. So like, for 1 sample condition, patient 2 and 3 might be close, but for another sample condition, are patient 2 and 3 still close, or are they completely different? I have 5 sample type conditions per patient that I'm investigating. I ran correlation tests already and stuff, so I'm really just looking for any other patterns. I'm at an initial investigative stage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ggplot_build`, but as other commenters mentioned, there may be better ways to get this information.

```
st1 <- ggplot(dt1, aes(Cl_total_18.0, pLPE_18.0, label = patient_ID)) +
  geom_point(size=0.5, shape=16) +
  geom_density_2d_filled(alpha = 0.5) 

dt2 <- ggplot_build(st1)$data[[2]]
summary(dt2 %>% mutate_if(is.character, as.factor))

head(dt2)
       fill          level        x        y piece  group subgroup level_low
1 #440154FF (0e+00, 1e-04] 1.920662 3366.463     1 -1-001        1         0
2 #440154FF (0e+00, 1e-04] 1.912940 3366.463     1 -1-001        1         0
3 #440154FF (0e+00, 1e-04] 1.896543 3366.463     1 -1-001        1         0
4 #440154FF (0e+00, 1e-04] 1.880145 3366.463     1 -1-001        1         0
5 #440154FF (0e+00, 1e-04] 1.863747 3366.463     1 -1-001        1         0
6 #440154FF (0e+00, 1e-04] 1.847350 3366.463     1 -1-001        1         0
  level_high level_mid nlevel n PANEL colour size linetype alpha
1      1e-04     5e-05  0.125 6     1     NA  0.5        1   0.5
2      1e-04     5e-05  0.125 6     1     NA  0.5        1   0.5
3      1e-04     5e-05  0.125 6     1     NA  0.5        1   0.5
4      1e-04     5e-05  0.125 6     1     NA  0.5        1   0.5
5      1e-04     5e-05  0.125 6     1     NA  0.5        1   0.5
6      1e-04     5e-05  0.125 6     1     NA  0.5        1   0.5
```

[image]

Comment: I was looking at ggplot_build, but I don't think I understand it. From that data, how can you tell what color/ level the points are falling within? It looks to me like all the points have the same level, but on the plot, they clearly are in various different levels, so I'm just confused.